# UserManager.FindByName() throwing EntityCommandExecutionException. Why is it using "EXTENT1"."USERNAME1"?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using Oracle DB, Entity Framework, Microsoft ASP.NET Identity, OWIN, and [OWIN-MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth).

Inside the execution of `UserManager.FindByName(name)`, I'm getting: "EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition." The internal exception is OracleException: ORA-00904: "Extent1"."USERNAME1": invalid identifier."

It is entirely true that I don't have a column named "USERNAME1" in the database, and it makes sense that the Identity framework can't find that column. The trouble is: I don't know why it's looking for that column to begin with. The IdentityUser.UserName is mapped explicitly in the DbContext like so:

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.UserName).HasColumnName("USERNAME");`

I searched my code for "USERNAME1" just in case I had an ill-defined magic string somewhere, but there are no results found in my code. I've searched for this error, but it seems like I'm the only one getting this kind of error from inside the framework.

Can anyone think of anyplace where its getting this column name and how I can correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a join on the username column?

Comment: you should show at least the code you are using and the relevant part of the mapping.

Comment: @amy I'm not 100% sure I understand the question. The query itself is coming from inside Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.FindByName(UserManager`2 manager, String userName), so I don't know if it's joining. The username column isn't referenced by any foreign keys, and I don't see any queries within my own code that join on the column.

Comment: These "phantom" columns happen when you tell EF that column A on one entity is a primary/foreign key of a column B on another entity.  If the relationship is misconfigured, what happens is one of the columns is duplicated with a number added, and *that* column is used as a key, not your original intended column.  It's a matter of how your entities are set up.  Do you have any other references to `username` from the configuration code that uses `modelBuilder`?

Comment: @Amy Thanks for the info. The issue was pretty close to that. Basically, I imported the entities as code-first from database and then marked the class as inheriting from IdentityUser, but forgot to delete the USERNAME column from the autogenerated code, so the class as two properties, the autogenerated USERNAME and the inherited UserName, that both map to the same database column. 

I owe you an accepted answer if you want to post your info on phantom columns as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Submitted as an answer.  This is a fairly common problem in EF.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "phantom" columns happen when you tell EF that column A on one entity is a primary/foreign key of a column B on another entity. If the relationship is misconfigured, what happens is one of the columns is duplicated with a number added, and that column is used as a key, not your original intended column. It's a matter of how your entities are set up.